# How do i turn on or off the Visual Studio python (Jupyter) interactive window (2019) when executing code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

At the moment my Visual Studio 2019 python extension right away starts the interactive Jupyter window when executing python code.

I don't want this anymore. I would like it to run the code in the terminal instead.

How do I switch between interactive window and terminal as a default setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1: Change setting in Visual Studio itself** 
You find this setting in File -> Preferences -> Settings.
Then look under Extensions -> Python
Change option 'Datascience: Send selection to interactive window'.
 
You can turn this option on or off.
[image: visual studio python interactive window option setting]

**Option 2: Modify settings.json** 
Alternatively, you can edit the settings.json file. 
On Windows, for me, this file is located in folder: 
C:\Users\Your_User_Name\AppData\Roaming\Code\User

Set the following option in settings.json to true or false:

```
"python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
```

My settings.json looks like this then:

```
{
    "python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
    "python.insidersChannel": "daily",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast"
}
```